# How to Custom TabHost views?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-fragmentactivity

i'm trying to custom my tabHost but I can't do as I want..

I want to create a tabHost like this picture

[image: TabBar iOS7]

But my result it's totaly different

[image: TabHost Android]

I have icons but I can't put text and icons smaller.

Here is my code to create TabHost

```
public class AppMainTabActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    /* Your Tab host */
    private TabHost mTabHost;

    /* A HashMap of stacks, where we use tab identifier as keys..*/
    private HashMap<String, Stack<Fragment>> mStacks;

    /*Save current tabs identifier in this..*/
    private String mCurrentTab;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /*
         *  Navigation stacks for each tab gets created..
         *  tab identifier is used as key to get respective stack for each tab
         */
        mStacks             =   new HashMap<String, Stack<Fragment>>();
        mStacks.put(AppConstants.TAB_A, new Stack<Fragment>());
        mStacks.put(AppConstants.TAB_B, new Stack<Fragment>());
        mStacks.put(AppConstants.TAB_C, new Stack<Fragment>());
        mStacks.put(AppConstants.TAB_D, new Stack<Fragment>());

        mTabHost                =   (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(listener);
        mTabHost.setup();

        initializeTabs();
    }


    private View createTabView(final int id) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tabs_icon, null);
        ImageView imageView =   (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_icon);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(id));
        return view;
    }

    public void initializeTabs(){
        /* Setup your tab icons and content views.. Nothing special in this..*/
        TabHost.TabSpec spec    =   mTabHost.newTabSpec(AppConstants.TAB_A);
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(-3);
        spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                return findViewById(R.id.realtabcontent);
            }
        });
        spec.setIndicator(createTabView(R.drawable.connection_tab_state_btn)); //See the code below
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);


        spec                    =   mTabHost.newTabSpec(AppConstants.TAB_B);
        spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                return findViewById(R.id.realtabcontent);
            }
        });
        spec.setIndicator(createTabView(R.drawable.search_tab_state_btn));
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);


        spec                    =   mTabHost.newTabSpec(AppConstants.TAB_C);
        spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                return findViewById(R.id.realtabcontent);
            }
        });
        spec.setIndicator(createTabView(R.drawable.alertes_tab_state_btn));
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);


        spec                    =   mTabHost.newTabSpec(AppConstants.TAB_D);
        spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                return findViewById(R.id.realtabcontent);
            }
        });
        spec.setIndicator(createTabView(R.drawable.settings_tab_state_btn));
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);
    }
....
}
```

Here is my code for the R.drawable.connection_tab_state_btn

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/connection_tab_layer_btn_tap" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/connection_tab_layer_btn" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/connection_tab_layer_btn_tap" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/connection_tab_layer_btn"/>
</selector>
```

And connection_tab_layer_btn_tap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_selected"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/user_picto" android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And connection_tab_layer_btn

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_unselected"/>
     <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/user_picto" android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I hope someone can help me :s

Thanks a lot !
Best regards